# How do I solve this apt-get issue in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

No matter what I do, for ex: apt-get clean or apt-get install, or apt-get upgrade,, etc I always get this error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:


/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distupgrade_1%3a0.220.8_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a0.196.14_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a0.196.14_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.19_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-urllib3_1.7.1-1ubuntu4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I solve this problem? It seems like I am unable to install anything on my ubuntu.

Comment: do you have space left on your install device? `df -h` shows this. do you use apt-get with sudo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Could be similar to this issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642173

Comment: @cari, Yes, I do have lots of space left :(

Comment: did you try to remove the packages manually with `rm /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distupgrade_1%3a0.220.8_all.deb` etc?

Comment: @cari yes I did that but no help :(

Comment: @cari do  you know how to reinstall the whole linux kernel from scratch again?  Does that solve ?

Comment: kernel has nothing to do with that, its most likely something wrong with your apt.

Comment: I wonder if you encounter the same from the GUI or only in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Try sudo apt-get autoremove
Then sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3

Comment: When I do sudo apt-get autoremove I get the same error. If I do sudo apt-get --reinstall python3 I get the same error :(